# chef-client failed to register to chef-server

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to install chef-client on node manually. The followings are my steps.

1. Download and install chef_12.2.1-1_amd64.deb
2. On node, mkdir /etc/chef
3. scp client.pem and validator.pem from chef-server to /etc/chef on node
4. Create client.rb on /etc/chef with the below content

client.rb

```
log_level     :info
log_location    STDOUT
chef_server_url   "https://192.168.100.118/organizations/hello"
validation_client_name "hello-validator"
client_key      "/etc/chef/client.pem"
validation_key  "/etc/chef/validation.pem"
```

5. Run chef-client on node
   I got the following error. Could anyone help on this? Did I miss anything? Thanks.

Error

```
[2015-04-10T04:27:42-04:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
Starting Chef Client, version 12.2.1
[2015-04-10T04:27:42-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.2.1 ***
[2015-04-10T04:27:42-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 7100
[2015-04-10T04:27:44-04:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: 192.168.100.118 - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

=============================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "controller"
=============================================================================

Unexpected Error:
-----------------
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

[2015-04-10T04:27:44-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.327701886 seconds
[2015-04-10T04:27:44-04:00] ERROR: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
[2015-04-10T04:27:44-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: What is this client.pem? In my workstation there is one user.pem, organization.pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to additionally configure your chef client with the trusted SSL certs as described in the following document:

https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_security.html

Alternatively disable SSL verification, by adding the following to your client.rb file:

```
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

PS

- Have you considered using "knife bootstrap" to setup chef on new nodes? A lot easier and will do most of this hard work for you.

Comment: Hi Mark I'm trying to build an environment without the Internet. chef-client on nodes needs to be installed from deb, so I don't use knife bootstrap. According to chef client security, SSL cert generated by the Chef server must be downloaded to any machine from which knife and/or the chef-client will make requests to the Chef server, but how should we "download" it from server? I directly copied it from server to node.  Yes, the node can register to the server successfully. Are there any smart ways? Why can't we use knife ssl fetch to pull down SSL cert, like workstation? Anyway, thank a lot.

Comment: @talihsu The behaviour of the knife bootstrap command can be customized using templates. See: https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#custom-templates  Might require some tweaking for your environment but would be worth the time spent

Comment: @talihsu If you're writing a custom template you can include a call to "knife ssl fetch". For more details see: http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/

Comment: @talihsu And finally knife bootstrap has a "--node-ssl-verify-mode" attribute which switches off SSL validation in the target node's client.rb.